# auto assembling mdadm created RAID - initramfs doesn't change

Tags: mdadm, initramfs

(Ubuntu 10.10 + mdadm 3.1.4) I have my raid described in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf:

```
HOMEHOST <system>    
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=46e68921:eea24d1d:e933eee8:192d55bc
ARRAY /dev/md/Volume0 container=46e68921:eea24d1d:e933eee8:192d55bc member=0  
UUID=b39c8d9d:ab2fcd08:f4559292:981754f1
```

I have also done the following:

```
update-initramfs –k all –u
```

BUT my RAID does not automatically assemble upon boot. I actually have to run the following on command line:

```
sudo mdadm -As
```

in order for the RAID to initialize. I read that you are supposed to run that update-initramfs command if you change your mdadm.conf, but it appears that it didn't really do anything. What am I missing?

Comment: What does `grep DEVICE /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` report?

Comment: @Steven Monday - it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

make sure your initramfs includes the correct modules, eg

```
echo raid1 >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
update-initramfs -u
```

those are needed to detect/assemble the raid during boot